# Ipad delete button not working in UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a few UItextfields connected to delegates, which have the function deleteCharactersInRange, to delete comas. I just found out that if I start editing one of these fields, write any characters, and then I want to delete them, the iPad delete button the the keyboard is not working. it doesn't delete anything.

Why??

This is the code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)tf shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)r replacementString:(NSString *)str
{
    if (tf == namegroup) {
        if ([str isEqualToString:@","]) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }

    if ([[newmessagename text] length] + [str length] - r.length > 30) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }

    if (tf != namegroup ||tf != newmessagename){
    return YES;
        }
}
```

Comment: show your code for `deleteCharactersInRange` and any other UITextField delegates you have

Comment: actually, the button works for newmesagename and namegroup

Comment: ok. put a breakpoint in the beginning of your method and step through it to see WHEN it actually returns `NO`. pretty sure you must be returning `NO` somewhere you shouldn't, so when you hit delete and the delegate returns `NO` in `deleteCharactersInRange` nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the code to this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)tf shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)r replacementString:(NSString *)str
{
if (tf == namegroup) {
    if ([str isEqualToString:@","]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

if (tf == newmessagename) {
if ([[newmessagename text] length] + [str length] - r.length > 30) {

    return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
}
```